# SQL query get business days from two date columns

Tags: mysql, sql, calendar

I have a sql table with two columns. One column is named dateUpdated, and the other is named dateReported. I wish to create a third column, one that holds the integer value of business days between dateUpdated and dateReported for each row. dateUpdated will ALWAYS be a date after or on the dateReported value. For example, the table may look like:

```
DATE UPDATED   Date Reported
2015-06-23     2015-06-02
2015-06-05     2015-06-04
2015-06-23     2015-06-15
2015-06-17     2015-06-04
2015-06-23     2015-06-27
2015-06-23     2015-06-04
2015-06-08     2015-06-04
```

The third column should be the number of business days between the two columns for each row. My current sql looks like this

```
select date(time_of_update) as updated, 
rep.date_reported as dateReported
from history hist left join reports rep
on hist.name = rep.name
left join calendar cal 
on rep.date_reported = cal.calendar_date;
```

my calendar table has a column of all of the dates as well as an associate column that marks if they are business days. For example, I could run something like

```
select sum(is_business_day) from calendar where 
calendar_date between '2015-06-02' and '2015-06-23';
```

and I would get 16 days. I was wondering how I could merge these two in order to get the two aforementioned columns as well as the third one.

A subquery is acceptable, if that is the only way to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `dt_tbl` is your table with dateUpdated and dateReported, and `calendar` is your table of calendar dates, then do this:

```
select
 a.dateUpdated
, a.dateReported
, sum(is_business_day) num_business_days
from
 dt_tbl a
left join
 calendar c on c.calendar_date between a.dateReported and a.dateUpdated
group by
 a.dateUpdated
, a.dateReported
```